# Inverting a regex pattern in R to match all left and between a giving set of strings

Tags: r, regex

Hello everyone I hope you guys are having a good one,

I have multiple and long strings of text in a dataset, I am trying to capture all text between , after and before a set of words, I will refere to this words as keywords

```
keywords= UHJ, uhj, AXY, axy, YUI, yui, OPL, opl, UJI, uji
```

if I have the following string:

```
UHJ This is only a test to AXY check regex in a YUI educational context so OPL please be kind UJI
```

The following regex will easily match my keywords:

```
UHJ|uhj|AXY|axy|YUI|yui|OPL|opl|UJI|uji
```

[image]

but since I am interested in capturing eveyrthing in between after and before those words, I am in some way wanting to capture the invert of my regex so that I can have something like this:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
[^UHJ|uhj|AXY|axy|YUI|yui|OPL|opl|UJI|uji]
```

[image]

with no luck and in the future the keywords may change so please if you know a regex that would work in R that can achive my desired output

Comment: Just split with this regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably just to split by your pattern. (Note this includes an empty string if the text starts with a keyword.)

```r
x <- "UHJ This is only a test to AXY check regex in a YUI educational context so OPL please be kind UJI"
keywords <- "UHJ|uhj|AXY|axy|YUI|yui|OPL|opl|UJI|uji"

strsplit(x, keywords)
# [[1]]
# [1] ""                         " This is only a test to "
# [3] " check regex in a "       " educational context so "
# [5] " please be kind "
```

Other options would be to use `regmatches()` with `invert = TRUE`. (This includes empty strings if the text starts or ends with a keyword.)

```r
regmatches(
  x,
  gregexpr(keywords, x, perl = TRUE),
  invert = TRUE
)
# [[1]]
# [1] ""                         " This is only a test to "
# [3] " check regex in a "       " educational context so "
# [5] " please be kind "
```

Or `stringr::str_extract_all()` with your pattern in both a lookbehind and a lookahead. (This doesn't include empty strings.)

```r
library(stringr)

str_extract_all(
  x, 
  str_glue("(?<={keywords}).+?(?={keywords})"
)
# [[1]]
# [1] " This is only a test to " " check regex in a "      
# [3] " educational context so " " please be kind "
```